# Environment variables for Eclipse

Tags: java, windows, eclipse

I created a path environment variable for the JDK: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_01\bin`, but when I try to open Eclipse I get the error:

`"Failed to load the JNI shared library "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_01\bin\..\jre\bin\client\jvm.dll"`.

Both my JDK and Eclipse are 64-bit. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common issue.

1.First check your Eclipse is 64-bit or 32-bit.

2.Then download 32-bit or 64-bit JDK.

3.SET PATH:

Copy Link Locations:

for 64-bit:
`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\bin`

for 32-bit:
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\bin`

4.Goto->System Properties->Advanced System Setting->Environmental variables->
New-> 
variable name: PATH
variable value: `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\bin`

variable value depending on 32 or 64-bit system.

5.Important 
32-bit Eclipse = 32-bit Java SDK
64-bit Eclipse = 64 Bit Java SDK

In case this problem still exists go to [eclipse.org](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/171274/)

Comment: Oh, thank you. Apperantly I was an idiot and used the 32-bit JDK.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please check the -vm argument in your eclipse.ini. It must point to the java executable. See http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure everything is 64-bit versions

64-bit OS

64-bit Java

64-bit Eclipse